# Programmatic way to Start/stop roslaunch

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Using python code, how to start/stop a .launch file?**

NOte: the launch file may contain several packages/nodes and parameters etc. just like a general .launch file we used to start for a gmapping/navigation task.

Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249383/programmatic-way-to-start/stop-roslaunch/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Several options are proposed in this related question:
[how to launch a launch file from python code](http://answers.ros.org/question/42849/how-to-launch-a-launch-file-from-python-code/)

the `subprocess` module can also be used to terminated processes, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321077/killing-a-script-launched-in-a-process-via-os-system) stackoverflow question.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-12-08**:
[this link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) may give us more official details about `subprocess` .

I also referred this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/10493/programmatic-way-to-stop-roslaunch

`subprocess` is **really cooool** after all~~ thx!!